# NPM dependency conflict?

Tags: node.js, npm

Say I have a project and inside his package.json we need dependency of jQuery 2.1.4 and bootstrap 3.3.5, and I set both to fix version instead using "^".

For bootstrap itself need a dependency of jQuery as well, but it need ^1.1.4.

Now what's gona happen with bootstrap, is it going to use the jQuery 2.1.4 or ^1.1.4?

Comment: It's going to use the latest `1.x.x` version. `2.1.4` is not compatible with `^1.1.4`, so it can't use that.

Comment: what if the bootstrap is set to latest 2.x.x, say latest one is 2.3.4, is it going to use 2.1.4 or download the 2.3.4?

Comment: Good question, that might depend on the npm version (i.e. v2 vs v3). I would think it would use `2.1.4`, but I'm not sure. Easy to find out yourself though, just create two packages with those dependencies...

Comment: Have you installed your bootstrap through npm packadge? If yes then in this case  bootstrap has own dependency of jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I just tested with other dependency, and it's just like you said, if they are all 2.x.x, it will  use the one from the project's version, and if is 1.x.x vs 2.x.x, it will download the new one. Thanks for the help!